# Is it possible to rename "iCloud Drive"?

Tags: icloud, macos

I do not like folder names with a space in them...

[image]

Can I rename `iCloud Drive` to another name, say, `iDrive`?

Answer (score 1):

The iCloud Drive item in the sidebar actually points to ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs. That said, it is not possible to rename the sidebar item, and do NOT rename the folder. Doing so will <strike>likely</strike> definitely cause iCloud Drive to stop functioning (if it even lets you rename it).